# Firebug - how do I see the request/response headers for "attachment" or other responses that trigger an open/save dialog?

Tags: header, firebug, attachment

***Environment***:

1. Firefox with Firebug and Jsonview addons installed and verified to work,
2. A web service that claims to send the response with "application/json" as the mime type; the service URL does **NOT** end in ".json".

***Problem***: Firefox puts up the open/save dialog instead of letting Jsonview to display the content.

***Question***: How do I see the response headers/content in Firebug for attachments or other responses that otherwise trigger an open/save dialog?

***Related question***: Is it possible to see headers/content in Firebug for responses that are targeted for popup windows?

Would like to avoid installing other plugins or network monitors if at all possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that Firebug needs to be "refreshed" when you want it to display a request with `Content-Disposition: attachment`:

Try to switch to another Firefox tab, where Firebug is not activated, and then switch back to your current tab. Firebug will get refreshed and show also previously invisible request in its Net panel.

**EDIT**

Now it's known issue [7264](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7264)

Comment: +1, while not a solution, this workaround seems to work, do you know the bug ID at firebug (if any) to track this further ?

Comment: @RaduMaris: Yes, now you can track it as an issue [7264](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7264)